# Conditional logic on flux of messages from reactor-kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I need to process flux of message from kafka topic using reactor-kafka. What should I achieve are these steps:

1. Read messages from kafka topic as flux.
2. Try to send each message to external system.
3. In case of success log that event, in case of failure - send message to another topic.
4. Manually acknowledge processed messages (important: in order).

I've found in [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#kafka-source-sink) example of building reactive pipeline (just receiving message from one topic and sending it to another) with manual acknowledgement of messages:

```
sender.send(KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                         .receive()
                         .map(m -> SenderRecord.create(transform(m.value()), m.receiverOffset())))  
      .doOnNext(m -> m.correlationMetadata().acknowledge());
```

But how can I send to another topic one part of processed messages and skip another part, but in the end make acknowledgements for all processed messages in order?